# How can i use CompositeCommand for saving a NEW employee with details

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a module which has a multiple tabs. Tab1-Employee details, Tab2 - Employee Assignments, Tab3 - Employee Vacation.

The module should allow the user to enter details in multiple tabs and click on SaveAll button.  The problem is the employeeid is generated by saving the data on first tab.  This is required for saving other tabs.  How can i achieve this scenerio?  Should i use Composite command/Region context or something else?

Appreciate your response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats the problem here.

To save all the information you need to save the information from the first tab and then the others, thats no problem. If you're using MVVM (wich you should) then the ViewModel should have access to the data, and be able to save the data.

Then it is just a matter of how the view is designed, doesn't matter if it is a TabControl or not. Just put a Command (just the usual DelegateCommand) inside the ViewModel and save first the information of the first tab. After that save the other information using the employeeid just generated.

With this scenario you could also add some validation to the ViewModel (see INotifyDataErrorInfo) and desactivate or activate the command whenever you want.